# Excel VBA Macro--Search For Column names and then copy into defined columns on another template worksheet in same workbook Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I can't seem to get this to work, I don't see where there is an issue.

It compiles fine, but it does nothing on my sheets. I am trying to write a macro that will Copy data by column header and paste into another template sheet within the same workbook with the same header.

*For example*, copy data under column "Time Started" on the import sheet, copy the new data, and paste into "Time Started" column on the Main sheet.

```
Sub CopyByHeader()

Dim shtImport As Worksheet, shtMain As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, f As Range
Dim rngCopy As Range, rngCopyTo

Set shtImport = ActiveSheet ' "import" - could be different workbook
Set shtMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

For Each c In Application.Intersect(shtImport.UsedRange, shtImport.Rows(1))
    'only copy if >1 value in this column (ie. not just the header)
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Application.CountA(c.EntireColumn) > 1 Then
        Set f = shtMain.Rows(1).Find(what:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopy = shtImport.Range(c.Offset(1, 0), _
                shtImport.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp))
            Set rngCopyTo = shtMain.Cells(Rows.Count, _
                f.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            'copy values
            rngCopyTo.Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rngCopy.Value
        End If
    End If
 Next c

 End Sub
```

---

I changed to this, which is super slow...any thoughts??:

```
Sub ImportTimeStudy()
Dim myHeaders, e, x, wsImport As Worksheet, wsMain As Worksheet
Dim r As Range, c As Range

myHeaders = Array(Array("Time Started", "Time Started"), Array("Description of the task", "Description of the task"), Array("Level", "Level"), Array("Location", "Location"), Array("Targeted", "Targeted"), Array("System", "System"), Array("Process Code", "Process Code"), _
            Array("Value Stream", "Value Stream"), Array("Subject", "Subject"), Array("BU", "BU"), Array("Task Duration", "Task Duration"), Array("Activity Code", "Activity Code"))

Set wsImport = Sheets("Import")
Set wsMain = Sheets("Main")

For Each e In myHeaders

    Set r = wsImport.Cells.Find(e(0), , , xlWhole)

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Set c = wsMain.Cells.Find(e(1), , , xlWhole)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            wsImport.Range(r.Offset(1), wsImport.Cells(Rows.Count, r.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
            wsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp)(2)
        Else
            msg = msg & vbLf & e(1) & " " & wsMain.Name
        End If
    Else
        msg = msg & vbLf & e(0) & " " & wsImport.Name
    End If

Next

If Len(msg) Then
    MsgBox "Header not found" & msg

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that the variable dimensions appear to be incorrect. when you type `Dim rngCopy As Range, rngCopyTo` only the first `rngCopy` is declared as a range, you are declaring the second `rngCopyTo` as a variant type variable. This doesn't directly impact your problem, but should be noted as it is a bad habbit that will cause you trouble coding down the road.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code ? If it doesn't copy any data, then some of your tests are not doing what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote your loops to be 2 `for` loops, give this a try:
(comments in-line)

```
Sub CopyByHeader()


Dim shtImport As Worksheet
Dim shtMain As Worksheet
Set shtImport = ActiveSheet ' "import" - could be different workbook
Set shtMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

Dim lCopyColumn As Long
Dim lCopyRow As Long
Dim lLastRowOfColumn As Long

'- for each column in row 1 of import sheet
For lCopyColumn = 1 To shtImport.Cells(1, shtImport.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    '- check what the last row is with data in column
    lLastRowOfColumn = shtImport.Cells(shtImport.Rows.Count, lCopyColumn).End(xlUp).Row

    'if last row was larger than one then we will loop through rows and copy
    If lLastRowOfColumn > 1 Then
        For lCopyRow = 1 To lLastRowOfColumn
            '- note we are copying to the corresponding cell address, this can be modified.
            shtMain.Cells(lCopyRow, lCopyColumn).Value = shtImport.Cells(lCopyRow, lCopyColumn).Value
        Next lCopyRow
    End If
Next lCopyColumn

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, the only problem is that my headers on "Main" are being overwritten. Is there any way to dictate where the information is pasted? The template is designed for anything below row 6, so needs pasting into row 7. Thanks if you can help!

Comment: add a plus 6 into the paste line so that it looks like this `shtMain.Cells(lCopyRow+6, lCopyColumn).Value = shtImport.Cells(lCopyRow, lCopyColumn).Value` I'm not 100% on how you're spreadsheet headers are laid out, but if you need to offset where things are going, do it there.

Comment: The issue I'm having now is that if the Import tab on the sheet has columns in different order than the template, it will just import into the wrong columns.  (Example, if data is pasted into the Main sheet, but the "Time Started Column" was moved to another column, it will paste "Time Started" under the wrong column)...Is there any way to match data to column header between two sheets?  Is vlookup the best option?

Comment: Right now the `lLastRowOfColumn ` loops through the input columns and just pastes them directly to the output at the same location. if you need to dynamically find where to paste I'd recommend using a for loop through your destination sheet's header row to find which header matches the column you're about to paste the rows to.

Comment: ok, that definitely helps Gimp.  I'll give it a whirl.  Thanks again, you're the man.

Comment: I changed the entire code to this, which is pretty slow...thoughts?

Comment: @RCoy1978 need to see your new code to comment on how to optimize it for speed. perhaps post a new question?

Comment: Gimp, I put it within this thread and posted as an answer to my question, not sure if you can see it or not?